# Why does it not remove all zeroes from the list

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I haven't coded in Python for a long time and sometimes I'm quite confused.
When I have an array, like eg.: arr = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]
and say:

```py
for i in arr:
    if i == 0:
       arr.remove(i)
```

it is removing the two zeroes the way I want.
But if the array is something like: arr = [0, 0, 1], with the above method, one 0 will remain.
So could someone explain me why the behavior is like that? I don't find an explanation for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why your method doesn't work. The problem comes from the way you iterate.

In your example, your function seems to work for `arr = [0,1,0,3,12]` but not on your second array `arr2 = [0,0,2]` and returns `[0,2]`. One interesting thing to investigate then, is the fact that in your second example, you have two ***consecutive*** zeros.

Take a look at this code and try to execute it :

```py
for i in arr:
        print('i = '+str(i))
        if(i == 0):
            arr.remove(i)
```

With your first array, you noticed that your output is the one you expected but that was lucky. As a matter of fact, if you run the code above, you would see that it prints in your console :

```
> i = 0
> i = 0
> i = 12
```

So, actually, this means that your `remove` statement changes the array you iterate on. After a deletion, you skip an element in your array.

This means you should prefer another way, like the ones suggested in comments.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh yeah, this makes things more clear. But does this also mean,that it's not suggested to edit a list while iterating over it at the same time, not editing in the means to edit in a ways that the "iteration is edited" too?

Comment: It's indeed not recommended to modify a list while iterating over it. It reminds me of that ConcurrentModificationException error in Java. It is often better to generate a new list/array. This is what happens when you use a list comprehension (see @Óscar-lópez 's answer) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Better try this:

```
arr = [n for n in arr if n != 0]
```

This uses a list comprehension, it's a lot safer than what you're doing: removing the elements at the same time you're iterating is a bad idea, and you'll experience problems such as elements not being removed.

This is because the list size is reduced and the iterator traversing it will find less elements than it was expecting when the iteration began.

Comment: if n != 0 you mean

Comment: Kind of, but actually I wanted to understand why in the first example array it worked, but it the second, just one 0 was removed.

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e behavior will be erratic, in the second it failed because the elements are contiguous.

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e `list(filter(None,arr))` is another option but it removes all "*Falsy*" values.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Ah I see, thank you so much..now I understand! I was soo curious when I saw this, but now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter out your zeros with the built-in function [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
arr = list(filter(None, arr))
```

you have to pay attention if you use `filter` function with `None` as first parameter, this will apply `bool` over your items if you have  elements like `None`, `0` or the empty string `''` the result will be the same, `False` and all these elements will be filtered out, for safety reasons you may use:

```
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x != 0 , arr))
```

Comment: Better pass a lambda, passing None is a bit hacky and you can get unexpected results.

Comment: for OP example where all the items are ints will work, but I will add a link to the documentation

Comment: @ÓscarLópez What exactly do you mean by unexpected results ?

Comment: @Ch3steR for example: if you had a list with boolean, numeric and None values but you only wanted to remove the zeroes, this approach will remove all falsey values.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yes, that's what what I have written under your answer. kederrac it's worth mentioning this point.So, it would be clear for beginners and future readers.

Comment: I hope is better now